# White border in the "nav" part in CSS

Tags: css

I am coding CSS from scratch for the first time and I am getting a lot of trouble to make it the perfect way.

As you can see in this image, the blue menu in the top has a white border.

[image: Website]

My current css code for nav is:

```
nav, footer {
    font-family: "rogue-sans-ext", sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    border-width: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

nav {
    background-color: #005EFF;
    width: 100%;
    position: static;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

By the way, I can't figure out how to center vertically the text of the nav items. I have tried the vertical-align option, the line-height method and the absolute positioning and negative margin, but none seems to work properly.

Thanks,
mikeysantana

Answer (score 2):

Probably, your problem is given by the default `body` padding value applied by browser.

Try applying this style:

```
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello, Christian!
Completely forgot about that! Thank you so much!